# Unable to setState with array of objects

Tags: arrays, reactjs, setstate

I'm trying to setState of an empty array with an array of objects on component load.

I've tried new ES6 syntax, I've tried mapping, join, etc but can't get it to work.

The console output of the array I'm trying to insert (not push) into my state looks correct.

```
mapped arrayObj : [{"word":"teacher","correct":true,"image":"/Assets/Art/Icons/teacher.png"},{"word":"backpack","correct":false,"image":"/Assets/Art/Icons/backpack.png"},{"word":"paper","correct":false,"image":"/Assets/Art/Icons/paper.jpg"}]
```

Here's the function where I'm mapping my array of objects and then I'm trying to setState of my empty answersObj.

```
mapArray(){

    const arrayObj = this.state.data.answers.map(obj => obj);
    let shuffledObjArray = [{}];

    shuffledObjArray = this.shuffleArray(arrayObj)



    this.setState({
        answersObj: shuffledObjArray
    })

    return shuffledObjArray;
}
```

I call the mapArray function when the component loads

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.mapArray();
}
```

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you mean by "unable" like what error you are seeing or what erroneous results you are seeing.
Also, that return statement won't really do anything because setState will trigger a rerender. 
Actually, more context in general would be helpful for this question.

Comment: The biggest problem is the array remains empty. It's as if the state isn't actually updating. If I log the array after setting state, it's still empty.

Comment: FYI you don’t need `arrayObject`, I would use `const { answers } = this.state.data` instead. As you are not doing anything with the data on your `.map()` just returning it as it was prior. Also an array is not an object. I suggest `shuffledObjArray`, is renamed to `shuffledAnswers`, it does not need an empty object, `[]` is good enough. It has more context and is descriptive to what you are doing 

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions Neil. I'll take a look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't forget that setState is async function, so the state doesn't sets immediately.

For example this piece of code works for me:

```
    async componentDidMount() {

     await this.mapArray();

    console.log(this.state)

}
```

the obj state gets the value it needs, while w/o the async/await it would print empty state.

Therefore, if you need to render the data from that state I'd suggest making 'dataLoaded' bool and render the data only if the data finished loading.

[image]